# Jest looks like not correctly processing simple import

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs

Running `NPM test` results in failure.
Looks like es6 import is not working properly:

```
import adder from '../adder'
```

More info about the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/DanielAtKrypton/express-webpack/issues/1).

I tried adding the following snippet to .babelrc file according to jest recommendation and installing transform-es2015-modules-commonjs.

```
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
```

This is the ofending file: adder.test.js.

```
javascript
import adder from '../adder'

describe('Adder', () => {
  test('adds two numbers', () => {
    expect(adder(5, 3)).toEqual(8)
  })
})
```

Here is the result of `npm test`:

```
$ npm test

> express-webpack@1.0.0 test C:\Users\Daniel\Workspaces\Web\express-webpack
```

> jest

```
 FAIL  src/js/test/adder.test.js
  Adder
    × adds two numbers (1ms)

  ● Adder › adds two numbers

    TypeError: (0 , _adder.default) is not a function

      3 | describe('Adder', () => {
      4 |   test('adds two numbers', () => {
    > 5 |     expect(adder(5, 3)).toEqual(8)
        |            ^
      6 |   })
      7 | })

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/js/test/adder.test.js:5:12)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.304s, estimated 4s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: Welcome Daniel, please show your adder file, because it looks like you are not using default export in adder.js properly.

Comment: Surprisingly today I noticed there was no code inside adder.js file. After I added the code now jest test passes.

Comment: Yes, I looked at your GitHub repo and found that the addr.js file was empty. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no code inside adder.js [file](https://github.com/DanielAtKrypton/express-webpack/blob/6b25a33e329657f36223c4370cef0d63e6c9ecab/src/js/adder.js).
After udating [adder.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DanielAtKrypton/express-webpack/master/src/js/adder.js), jest test passes.

```
 PASS  src/js/test/adder.test.js
  Adder
    √ adds two numbers (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.805s
Ran all test suites.
```